# Firebase Functions - sending pushes and got an error saying "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM and Firebase Functions in order to send push notifications to users, and have an issue. I am getting an error saying "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" and believe this is caused by a line of :

```
const tokens = Object.keys(afterData.fcm_tokens)
```

However when printing this out to console it seems to have its values in an array form so the tokens wouldn't be null :

```
sendPush
[ 'my_long_fcm_token01', 'my_long_fcm_token02', 'my_long_fcm_token03' ]
```

Below is the full error description:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at exports.sendPush.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:57:27)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

It is my push function:

```
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/user_pushes/{uid}').onWrite((change, context) => {

    const afterData = change.after.val();
    const tokens = Object.keys(afterData.fcm_tokens)
    console.log(tokens)

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            uid: afterData.sender_uid,
            title: afterData.sender_name,
            subtitle: afterData.roomId, // I need this property as room id
            body: afterData.message,
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default',
            mutable_content: 'true',
        },
        data: {
              image_url: afterData.image_url
        }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
});
```

EDIT : As per suggestion I edited my question to 1 to be more focused on.

Comment: Your `change.after.val()` function is apparently returning null.

Comment: Thank you Robert Harvey for your advice. I am new to Javascript, can you be specific how it should be fixed?

Comment: I would start by figuring out what that function does, and why it is returning null.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please limit yourself to a single question or issue per post.  Otherwise, it might get closed as "needs focus".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to response from Robert Harvey, I found what causes this error by digging into the `change.after.val()`. I didn't realise this returns nil because i thought it shouldn't, but actually it was because I was updating and removing the node at once for purpose. Due to removal of the node, the object returns nil and the error occurred, I think.

As I was using `onWrite()` the node was triggered unexpectedly twice, therefore I changed `onWrite()` to `onUpdate` and now it works as desired. For more detail please have a look at Doug Stevensons's great explanation :

[Value of firebase functions onwrite sometimes is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250888/value-of-firebase-functions-onwrite-sometimes-is-null)